# begin the string in C

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[50];
    printf("nhap chuoi : ");
    gets(a);

    //cat cac ki tu trang cuoi chuoi
    for (int i= strlen(a)-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(a[i]!=' ')
        {
            a[i+1]='\0';
        }
        break;
    }
    //cat cac ki tu trang dau chuoi
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(a); i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==' '&& a[i+1]!=' ');
        strcpy(a,a[i+1]);
    }
    printf("\nchuoi sau khi cat:");
    puts(a);
    return 0;
}//main
```

When I run program, it shows this error in line 17:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive].

Comment: `a[i+1]` is a `char`, not a `char*`. And [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714). Also store `strlen(a)` in a variable instead of calling it in each loop like that

Comment: `if(a[i]==' '&& a[i+1]!=' ');` doesn't do anything (check the semicolon)

Comment: @Từ Đức Sơn, can you explain what are you trying to do with code you wrote?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to trim spaces off the start and end of the string?

Comment: Actually, `gets` was considered so harmful / broken that it was **removed** from the language with C11.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if(a[i]==' '&& a[i+1]!=' ');
strcpy(a,a[i+1]);
```

does not make sense. First the semicolon after the if statement makes it a no-op. And the `strcpy` is also incorrect.

I guess you want to strip out a single character and thus wanted to write `strcpy(a, &a[i+1])`. That second parameter needs to be a pointer (`a[i+1]` is a `char`) That is however invalid as the source and destination overlap.

for possibly overlapping memory you need to use `memmove`, but there you have to specify the number of bytes to move (and not forget the terminating zero): `memmove(a, &a[i+1], strlen(a)-i)`

(the number of chars to copy is `strlen(a)-(i+1)` and we need to add one for the terminating zero)

So that code becomes:

```
if(a[i]==' '&& a[i+1]!=' ') {
    memmove(a, &a[i+1], strlen(a)-i);
}
```